# How to connect RFID Module to Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

I brought 860mhz-960mhz UHF rfid reader module for chip card skimmer from follow link:

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/860mhz-960mhz-UHF-rfid-reader-module_60312310172.html

I want to do communication with arduino uno so is it possible to connect
[image]

VCC to VCC
GND to GND 
RX to TX 
TX to RX

and what is meaning of EN and GPIO if any one know please help me to do serial communication.

Answer (score 1):

Its just a simple RFID module based on UART working on 5V.  EN stands for enable, to enable the chip. It has to be connected to VCC too. Because its active high signal. GPIOs are general purpose io pins. No need of them if you are just reading from RFID.

Comment: thank you so much I will try to connect these and let you know